Typst Quarto Template in R
I'm using typst to create a template for Quarto pdf's in R. I'm formatting the typst-template.typ document I have in my files. Below is the code that works well with the typst software:
#place(
  top + left,
  dx: 0pt,
  dy: -20pt,
  rect(fill: rgb("FA8975FF"),
  width: 0.15cm, 
  height: 1cm),
)
#place(
  top + left,
  dx: -5pt,
  dy: -10pt,
  rect(fill: rgb("000000"),
  width: 100%, 
  height: 0.05cm),
)

And here is the R typ file that is not rendering right at all. How do I put two rectangles with each other in typst format in R? Are there any guides to transcribing typst format into R templates?
#let psc-report(
  title: "title",
  body,
) = {

// This sets the text for the entire document
set text(
  font: "Calibri",
  size: 10pt,
)

// This sets the paging formats
set page(
  "us-letter",
  margin: (
  left: 1in, 
  right: 1in, 
  top: 1in, 
  bottom: 1in
  ),
  background: [
  place(
    top + left,
    dx: 5pt,
    rect(
    fill: rgb("FA8975FF"), 
    width: 0.25cm, 
    height: 1cm
    )
    ),
  place(
    top + left,
    dx: 10pt,
    rect(
    fill: rgb("15397F"), 
    width: 100%, 
    height: 0.1cm
    )    
    )
    ],
    
    // not entirely sure how the footer page number works yet
  footer: align(
    grid(
      columns: (40%, 60%),
      align(
      horizon, 
      text(fill: rgb("15397F"), 
      size: 10pt, 
      counter(page).display("1")
      )
      ),
    )
  )
)

  body
}


I ran into a similar issue where I couldn't pass multiple arguments to background:. Instead I used a combination of the header: and footer: functions using methods referenced here. I also played around with using place outside of the set page() function, like they did here see lines 78 & 79. Not sure if this is what you need, but hopefully it helps a bit!

I think I have the code you need below. You didn't include an image so I'm not sure if this is your desired output. If you can include an image I can adjust the code as needed. The trick is to pull the place functions out of the set page() function.
I used the quarto create extension format command referenced here which set up the _extensions directory for typst. That created two .typ files: typst-show.typ and typst-template.typ.
Here is the typst-template.typ file with the rectangles and footer:
#let psc-report(
  title: "title",
  body,
) = {
set page(
  "us-letter",
  margin: (
  left: 1in, 
  right: 1in, 
  top: 1in, 
  bottom: 1in
  ),
  footer: align(
    grid(
      columns: (40%, 60%),
      align(
      horizon, 
      text(fill: rgb("15397F"), 
      size: 10pt, 
      counter(page).display("1")
      )),
    ))
)
  place(
    top + left,
    dx: 5pt,
    rect(
      fill: rgb("FA8975FF"), 
      width: 0.25cm, 
      height: 1cm))
          
  place(
    top + left,
    dx: 10pt,
    rect(
      fill: rgb("15397F"), 
      width: 100%, 
      height: 0.1cm))
  
}

Here is the typst-show.typ file:
#show: body => psc-report(
$if(title)$
  title: [$title$],
$endif$

$if(by-author)$
  authors: (
$for(by-author)$
$if(it.name.literal)$
    ( name: [$it.name.literal$]),
$endif$
$endfor$),
$endif$

$if(date)$
  date: [$date$],
$endif$
  body,
)


Thanks so much @EJump this is perfect and worked great. Knowing I needed to bring it out of the set page is really helpful for other edits! Cheers!
